# Break Loop if Index is Out Of Bounds of While Loop in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a while loop that looks like this:

```
while a[xp][yp] - a[xp-1][yp] == 0  and a[xp][yp] - a[xp+1][yp] == 0 and a[xp][yp] - a[xp][yp-1] == 0 and a[xp][yp] - a[xp][yp+1] == 0:
    c=randint(0,3)
    if c==0:
        xp=xp+1; yp=yp
    elif c==1:
        xp=xp-1; yp=yp
    elif c==2:
        xp=xp; yp=yp+1
    else:
        xp=xp; yp=yp-1
    xp=xp; yp=yp
```

The problem is that if xp or yp = 0 or n (the length of the array in either x direction or y, it is a square matrix), then the conditions in the while loop break down and I get an out of bounds error. I would simply like to get a new set of coordinates if xp=0 or xp=n or yp=0 or yp=n (I have a separate piece of code that does this) and let the while loop run again.

The nature of the code seems to be that about 1 in every 4 times the code runs without going out of bounds. I just need it to keep running until it happens to work.

Comment: Well, yes. You aren't checking that `xp` and `yp` are greater than `0` or that they are less than `len(a)` and `len(a[0]` (the "shape")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply check if the operation will push the index out of bounds, like so:

```
if c==0 and xp < len(a)-1:
  xp += 1
elif c==1 and xp > 0:
  xp -= 1
# etc...
```

This will make sure that `xp` stays in bounds *before* actually changing it, rather than looking at it afterwards.

---

The second problem is in your `while` statement - even if you make sure that `xp` and `yp` are in the bounds for the array, you could be checking *outside* in your initial condition:

```
while a[xp][yp] - a[xp-1][yp] == 0 and a[xp][yp] - a[xp+1][yp] == 0  \ 
  and a[xp][yp] - a[xp][yp-1] == 0 and a[xp][yp] - a[xp][yp+1] == 0:
```

Here, I'll assume that `a` has a size of 10 by 10 (indexes from 0 to 9). if we set `xp` to 0 and `yp` to 9, then this will work out to:

```
while a[0][9] - a[-1][9] == 0 and a[0][9] - a[1][9] == 0 \
      a[0][9] - a[0][10] == 0 and a[0][9] - a[0][10]:
```

`a[10]` will throw the out of bounds error, so you'll have to determine how to change the loop when the index is right on the boundaries of the array. Note that `a[9]` is still a valid index for the array - it's checking for the *next* index that is the problem.

As an aside, `a[-1]` *won't* actually throw an exception, although it's likely a logic error for you - [the negative index will access the final element in the array](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm#accessing).

---

A possible way to fix it, although it's dependent on what you need to do: Python will [short-circuit the `or` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not), so it is possible to write something like this without throwing an exception:

```
while (xp <= len(a)-2 or a[xp][yp]-a[xp+1][yp] == 0) and \
      (xp > 1         or a[xp][yp]-a[xp-1][yp] == 0) and #etc...
```

Here, if `xp` is *less* than `len(a)-2` (the first clause evaluates to true), the other half of the `or` statement won't be evaluated, the out of bounds exception won't occur, and the loop will continue to run (as long as `xp` is also greater than 1, and the rest of the statement also evaluates to true).

Comment: This definitely seems like it should work, but I still get the out of bounds error and I can't see why... is it because when it goes out of bounds nothing is changed?

Comment: Ah, your second problem is in your if statement - will clarify momentarily.